# .NET Logging WebService

Tags: asp.net, web-services, logging

I work on some ASP.NET projects in collaboration with other developpers and I'm thinking about building a homemade logging solution. But before starting anything I would like to know if something similar to what I'm intended to code already exists.

I'm looking for a tool, framework or whatever, that can be used to create a logging webservice.

The service will be reachable by all our websites. It offers a set of methods to send logging information to the service which will store them in a database. We can imagine a method named "Trace(String message, TraceLevel level)" where the first argument can be an XML string containing a set of structured useful information (error, debug or access).

One interesting feature will be that people can subscribe to a set of logs. For example, if I'm working on a "AnotherStackOverlow.com" project and I want to receive error logs, I can easily subscribe to the system choosing the corresponding TraceLevel.

Has anyone already used a system like this?

I'm also interested in general comments about security issues, coding issues, design problems and so on.

Thanks

Comment: It is not a web service, but did you check elmah http://code.google.com/p/elmah/ ? More a component that has to be added to every web site, but it's quite efficient. There are rss feeds and other things alike for the subscription feature you are looking for too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion, doing logging through a web service is a very bad idea. You are relying on a connection between machines that may or may not be there which is going to lead to lost data.

I would take a look at [Elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) which is a fairly easy ASP.NET logging tool to use.

You can have Elmah do the logging for you. You can then write a separate application to aggregate all of the log data (which is pretty trivial if you configure Elmah to log to a database) so that it can be viewed from a single location.

Comment: +1 for elmah and for stating that the OP's idea isn't a good approach.